# Galaxy S4 not recognized by Android SDK on Windows

Tags: android, galaxy, samsung-mobile

My Galaxy S4 will not connect to ADB in the Android SDK on my Windows 2003 server.  It *does* work just fine on my Mac Mini running OS X 10.7, so clearly nothing is wrong with the phone or the USB cable.

When I connected it to the Mac for the first time, I got a RSA Certificate warning that displayed on the phone - this is supposed to happen, according to the instructions on the Android Developer site.  But it never happens when I connect it to the Windows PC.

I *have* downloaded the most recent version of the SDK.
I *have* enabled Developer Mode on the phone.
I *have* enabled USB Debugging on the phone.
I *have* installed the Samsung USB driver, downloaded directly from developer.samsung.com. (uninstalled and re-installed it several times, rebooted both the phone and the computer each time).

So - does anyone have any ideas at all about what might be going on here?  I'm at my wits end.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: I installed KIES, but it fails with some "missing DLL" error...   And using a different cable seems pointless to me -- the exact same cable works perfectly well on a Mac.  It's obviously some stupid thing wrong with Samsung's driver, I'm guessing?  Has anyone ever gotten a Galaxy S4 to work on a PC with the Android SDK?

Comment: Can't believe I missed that the first time I read over your question. Are you seriously running Windows 2003 Server? If the S4 didn't work on PCs, we would have heard about it by now. I'd say that ADB doesn't work on a ten-year-old OS. What's DLL are you missing? That might give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the system requirements listed on the [Android SDK download page on Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), only Windows XP and above is compatible with the full Android SDK, and Windows Server 2003 appears to be based on Windows 98. There may also be compatibility issues with KIES too, as [Samsung's website](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP) states that KIES is only compatible with XP and above. Therefore it is probably your OS that is the problem.

If you have another Android phone, try connecting that to your PC and installing the drivers. If it is not recognized, it is very likely to be your OS.